# Include not including some variables in PHP 7

Tags: php, include

I know this is little bit strange but some variables are undefined when including these variables.
This is my web structure:

details.php:

```
$login['server']    =   'server';                           
$login['database']  =   'db';                               
$login['username']  =   'user';
$login['password']  =   'pass';
define ('constant1' , 'ok');
```

main.php:

```
include ('subfile.php');
```

subfile.php:

```
echo $login;
echo constant1;
```

index.php:

```
include ('details.php');
include ('main.php');
```

And output is undefined $login and `ok`. I already tried with `get_included_files()` in subfile.php and this function shows details.php as included file.

Comment: I am totally new to php7 but as I know in php usually you cannot echo arrays :) is that maybe the problem?

Comment: no it should return convert error but this is variable undefined

Comment: or maybe the problem is that you did not define `$login=array()` in the beginning in your details file.

Comment: IT's working fine for me..No errors like you mentioned..Check whether all the php files are in same directory

Comment: Files are not in same directory but i have no include errors

Comment: Add an `echo` statement to each included file to make sure the files you think are being loaded are.

Comment: Including in php works in run time as just copying the contents of included file into the including file in the same position of the include ... which means there is a problem in your include, or you are not posting full details, because the code you just posted is working just fine here https://eval.in/626788